# Is there a way for VS code to imitate Dreamweaver's easy way for displaying Database results using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, visual-studio-code

Although Dreamweaver is not used much anymore, it used to have a great way to take a MySQL query and automatically create the PHP code for displaying the results into a table. It even would create the code for splitting the results in order to show them in pages (previous page, next page, last page etc).

Does VS code provide this functionality through some plugin? Or maybe some other widelly used tool like eclipse?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). _"Questions **asking us to recommend or find** a book, **tool, software library**, tutorial **or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow** as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."_

Comment: While this question is off topic and likely to be closed, a pointer would be to look at a framework - It takes the heavy lifting out of your code so you can focus on business logic and UI. I can't recommend any at this point though.

Comment: Thanks for the input, although I thought this question was more about "software tools commonly used by programmers", an editor functionality if you will, not  an external tool or a software library. Is there a more appropriate Stack Exchange site I can ask this question?

Comment: That refers to if you're having problems/issues with a specific tool (which can be on-topic since it usually have a concrete answer) while your question is asking us to recommend other tools (which includes plugins)  and is therefor off-topic.

Comment: No problem. It can be a fuzzy line sometimes :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin available Right now it only supports mysql and postgresql Databases Check It Out in the marketplace

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bajdzis.vscode-database

Comment: Please don't answer clearly off-topic questions. Doing that legitimizes them and might encourage the OP and future visitors to keep asking them. Let us all help out keeping SO on-topic instead.